# Update DIV contents with data from ASP.NET on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

For example, i have 2  blocks, one is visible and one is collapsed ( tab control ). The countriesList gets populated with data in codebehind (OnPageLoad):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50;i++ )
    countriesList.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<div class=\"list\"><div class=\"list-item\"><div class=\"list-item-content-wrapper\"><span class=\"list-item-content\">{0}</span></div></div></div>", i)));
```

---

```
<div class="frame" id="frame_1">
    <div class="listview">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="countriesList">
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="frame" id="frame_2">
    <div class="listview">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="citiesList">
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have to get data from server, when user selects some country, and then show it in a second  ( that is hidden currently ).

Is there a way, to populate the

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="citiesList">
</asp:Panel>
```

**Without requesting the whole page from the server again?**

I need to do the request on server side, not on client side.

Comment: The obvious answer is to use AJAX (either written yourself, or using the [`<asp:UpdatePanel>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by asp.net)

Comment: Use **WebMethod** to get data from server

Comment: @Suprabhat, WebMethod can only be used  to get static data, you cannot use it to access ASP.NET control

Comment: @Alek Correct Server control can't be accessed inside a webmthod. I agree with you but when return type is JSON you easily populate data in HTML elements without any postback. Does anything wrong what I have just said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your client side:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
            '__EVENTTARGET': '$GetSomeData',
            'param1': 'param1_value',
            'param2': 'param2_value'
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        alert("have html data:\n" + data);
        $('#YourControlId').html(data);
    }).fail(function (p1, p2, p3) {
        alert("error");
    });
```

Then on server side somewhere in control_load method:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    var et = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];

    switch (et)
    {
        case "$GetSomeData":
            var param1 = Request.Params["param1"];
            var param2 = Request.Params["param2"];
            var html_data = GetSomeData(param1, param2);

            response.ClearContent();
            response.ContentType = "text/html";
            response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            using (var outStream = response.OutputStream)
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outStream))
            {
                writer.Write(html_data);
            }

            response.Flush();
            response.SuppressContent = true;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: I will test that in the morning

Answer (score 0):

You can create an onchange event handler for your countries dropdown. Inside the event handler, make an AJAX request to the server (passing the country value as a parameter). Then just populate the inner HTML of the cities DIV with the response data.

Example (using jquery):

```
$('#Country').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<your url here>'
            , type: 'POST'
            , data: {
                country: $(this).val()
            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#citiesList').html(data);
        });
});
```

Comment: I need to do the request on server side, not on client side.